# Setting a layout to view.setEnabled(false) does not disable all child views

Tags: android, isenabled

I have a layout with several nested relative layouts.  Within the nested layouts I have form elements, such as `TextView`s, `EditText`s and `Button`s. The code is abbreviated just for this example:

```
Context con;
LinearLayout survey = new LinearLayout();
RelativeLayout question = new RelativeLayout();
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button btnAnswer = new Button(con);
btnAnswer.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
btnAnswer.addParams(params);
question.addView(btnAnswer);
TextView tvBtnLabel = new TextView(con);
btnAnswer.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
tvBtnLabel.setText("Some Label");

tvBtnLabel.addParams(params);
question.addView(tvBtnLabel);
survey.addView(question);
question.setEnabled(false);
//^^^^does not set child views to disabled state
```

When I set the entire nested Relative Layout to false, the `Button` and the `TextView` are not disabled.  I have to go in and set each child view to disabled individually.  Bug in android?  Is there a maximum nesting limit for disabling views?  I've checked the state and the relative layouts are indeed set to disabled.

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's a feature"

Comment: @KushtrimP. lol.  A frustrating feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Context con;
LinearLayout survey = new LinearLayout(con);
survey.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
                                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

RelativeLayout question = new RelativeLayout(con);
question.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  
              (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Button btnAnswer = new Button(con);
btnAnswer.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
btnAnswer.addParams(params);

question.addView(btnAnswer);
TextView tvBtnLabel = new TextView(con);
btnAnswer.setId(GlobalVars.getLatestId());
tvBtnLabel.setText("Some Label");

tvBtnLabel.addParams(params);
question.addView(tvBtnLabel);
survey.addView(question);
```

[**UPDATE**]

```
for (int i = 0; i < question.getChildCount(); i++) {
   View child = question.getChildAt(i);
   child.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: how does this change what I'm doing?

Comment: Because your codes, did not put views into `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. And also you did not `setLayoutParams` for `survey` and `question`

Comment: @KristyWelsh I found another solution for the issue, check the **UPDATE** of my answer.